# N-Gram Creator Not Retrieving Final Word

Tags: java, arraylist, n-gram

I am doing a project where I need to create 'n-grams' for analysis.  I currently have a method that does this for `int` 'n' and collates all the terms together, except for the last word in the ArrayList, which it totally ignores and I am unsure why?  Here is the output...

```
Original:  Making pancakes today? Need a recipe? Check https://t.co/lsrRy8CW22  #PancakeDay https://t.co/WiPX4joM4v

Bag of Words:  [make, pancak, today, recip, check, pancakeday]

2-gram: [make pancak, pancak today, today recip, recip check]

3- gram: [make pancak today, pancak today recip, today recip check]
```

As you can see, it skips the last word `pancakeday` and I am unsure why.

Here is the method...

```
    public void ngramCreator(int n){
    ngramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String word : bagOfWords){
        if (int i = 0 < bagOfWords.size() - n) {
            String ngram = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
                ngram += bagOfWords.get(i + j) + " ";
            ngram += bagOfWords.get(i + n - 1);
            ngramList.add(ngram);
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ngramList);
}
```

Thanks for all the help guys, totally appreciate it.

Comment: Try  i<=bagOfWords.size() - n. Thus you will access even the last bag element

Comment: that worked man! cheers :)!

Comment: @istovatis You should add it as an answer since it solved the OP's problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your bagOfWords contains n elements, you should iterate the whole list.
The following code should do the trick.

```
if (int i = 0 <= bagOfWords.size() - n) {
    // The rest ngrams implementation is correct
}
```